# Printing folders containing specific extension file in groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to find all the folders containing files of specific extension in groovy. I know how to do this in Bash. I would use something like

`find /folder-type f -name "*.png" -printf "%h"`

But how would I do it in groovy ?
So if the folder structure is

```
Folder
|-X
  |- pic1.png
  |- Y
     |-pic2.png
  |-Z
    |-A
    |-B
      |-pic3.png
```

In this case my desired output is X, X/Y,X/Z/B. Also I would like to store them as strings seperated by whitespace hence something like name = X X/Y X/Z/B.

I would do something like to get all files and folders

```groovy
def list = []
def dir = new File("path/to/folder/")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
   list << file
}
```

but I need path to folders which contains files with specific extension.

Comment: Don't tag a groovy question with a java tag please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import groovy.io.FileVisitResult
import groovy.io.FileType

def list=[]

new File('path/to/folder/').traverse(
    type         : FileType.FILES,
    nameFilter   : ~/.*\.png$/,   //ends with png
){f-> 
    list << f.parentFile          //add parent dir to list
    FileVisitResult.SKIP_SIBLINGS //don't continue dir scan on one file found
}
```

documentation for [File.traverse( Map, Closure)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#traverse(java.util.Map,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) method

Answer (score 0):

Get the "parent" (folder) of each file, and change the List to a Set to eliminate duplicates:

```groovy
def list = new LinkedHashSet()
def dir = new File("C:/prog/utility")
dir.eachFileRecurse (groovy.io.FileType.FILES) { file ->
   list << file.parentFile
}
```